# Analyzing code programmatically using Visual Studio compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, parsing, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I need to build programmatically a listing from C++ code fragment similar to compiling code with /d1reportAllClassLayout parameter in Visual Studio (see https://pigworlds.wordpress.com/2009/01/17/msvc-compiler-d1reportsingleclasslayout-d1reportallclasslayout/ for reference and example). This listing should include class members and virtual functions table info (class member names, types and offsets) in custom format.
To achieve this I need to somehow access AST generated by Visual Studio compiler. The task of generating this listing from C++ code could be implemented using Clang, but specifics of my task is that all data in this listing (member names, types and offsets) should be identical to that of Visual Studio compiler. For example, I'm not sure if Clang would generate the same member offsets in structures as Visual Studio compiler. 
Can anybody point me in right direction for achieving this? Is Clang actually enough for this purpose (I'm not that much familiar with it yet) or should I write Visual Studio extension? 
P.S. I understand that this question probably is not very well formed as my knowledge of the subject is pretty vague at the moment. I am ready to improve it if I get better understanding what I actually need to solve my task.

**Edit:**
Here's example of listing I need to compose:

```
ClassA

offset | name        | size | C++ type        

0x00   | {vfptr}     | 4    | ClassA::$vftable
0x04   | mID         | 4    | unsigned int
0x08   | mColor      | 16   | CColor
0x18   | mpFunc      | 4    | void (__cdecl *)(char isVisible)
0x1C   | mBuffer     | 16   | char[16]
```

Comment: What sort of analysis are you trying to do? Are you trying to figure out logical dependencies, how the code is structured, etc? Or are you more interested in the structure of the assemblies the compiler generates?

Comment: I need to collect and print in custom format data types information: list of structures declared in the code with their member names, offsets and types. /d1reportAllClassLayout report is very similar to what I need to achieve except it is lacking structure member types.

Comment: that's just telling me what information you're seeking, I'm looking more for what you intend to do with that information once obtained, that is what is the analysis you'll be building from that information.

Comment: I'm going to load this information into IDA disassembler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clang has proved to be a good choice for this task. 
Using Clang I was able to create a tool producing desired output with C++ classes description from their definitions in C++ files.

Comment: Including the offsets?